# Map is undefined after posting to Atlas (MERN Stack)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-context

I'm making a Todo list this time with using 'context'.
In my useEffect I fetch my items from my Atlas database and the items render fine using the map method. I then navigate (react-router-dom) to my add item page, add an item to my database which writes it to the database.

When I navigate back to my home page where the list of items should be it shows an error, 'map is undefined'.

I've been scratching my head with this all weekend and before I start again was wondering if anyone can spot my error?

Home.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useTodoContext } from "../hooks/useTodoContext";

const Home = () => {
    const { todos, dispatch } = useTodoContext()
   
    useEffect(() => {

        const fetchTodos = async () => {
            console.log('called')

            const response  = await fetch("/todos/items")
            const json = await response.json()
            if(response.ok){
                dispatch({ type: "SET_TODOS", payload: json})
            }
        }
        fetchTodos()
      
    }, [dispatch])
    if(!todos) return <h1>loading...</h1>
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {todos ?  
                <>
                {todos.todos.map((todo) => <h2 key={todo._id}>{todo.todo}</h2>)}
                </>
                : <p>loading...</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

AddTodo.js

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useTodoContext } from "../hooks/useTodoContext"

const AddTodo = () => {
    const { dispatch } = useTodoContext()
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("")

    const handler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const todo = { todo: userInput }

        const response = await fetch('/todos/item', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(todo),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })

        const json = await response.json()
        if(!response.ok) console.log('error')
        if(response.ok) {
            setUserInput('')
            console.log('new todo added', json)
            dispatch({
                type: 'CREATE_TODO',
                payload: json
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                add item
            </h1>
            <form onSubmit={handler}>
                <input 
                type="text"
                    value={userInput}
                    onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button type="submit">submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddTodo
```

TodoContext.js

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const TodoContext = createContext()

export const todoReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_TODOS':
            return {
                todos: action.payload
            }
        case 'CREATE_TODO':
            return {
                todos: [action.payload, ...state.todos.todos  ]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const TodosContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(todoReducer, {
        todos: null
    })

    return (
        <TodoContext.Provider value={{...state, dispatch}}>
            { children }
        </TodoContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

backend

server.js

```
require("dotenv").config()

const express = require('express')
const itemRoutes = require('./routes/items')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express()
app.use(express.json()) // parse incoming data
app.use('/todos', itemRoutes)

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(4000, () => {
            console.log('listening on port 4000, connected to db')
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

controller

```
const getTodos = (req, res, next) => {
    Todo.find().then(foundTodos => {
        res.json({
            message: "all items",
            todos: foundTodos
        })
    })
}
```

routes

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router() // create a router
const itemsController = require('../controllers/items')
router.get('/items', itemsController.getTodos)
router.post('/item', itemsController.createTodo)

module.exports = router
```

I thought I may be able to solve with conditional rendering but no luck

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Most-likely your `json` variable is `undefined`

Comment: My error message is this
'ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')'

Comment: This error means that in the expression `something.map`, `something` is `undefined`, not `map`. In your case it would be `todos.map`. I guess that when you call `dispatch({ type: "SET_TODOS", payload: json})`, `json` is `undefined`. Try adding `debugger` or `console.log` to check if it's true. You can also open dev tools and go to network tab to what is returned from that endpoint